# What are the units used for the dimensions of an Image Target on Target Manager?

Tags: android, vuforia

On Vuforia's Target Manager, whilst uploading an image target into the database, we are asked to provide the dimensions for the target.

Are these targets in Feet, or Inches, or centimetres, or millimetres?

Cookie points if you can tell me the dimensions of a normal soda can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size is in scene units. They are not a real unit. You can use whatever you want. It just affects how your objects are drawn.

For example, if you set width to 15 when it really is 15 centimetres, then when you move an object by 1 unit it moves it by 1 centimeter. The point is just to specify something so that Vuforia knows a size, otherwise it would have no idea.

EDIT: Here is also a link to Vuforia's [documentation](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/add-image-target-database) which also explains this (albeit a bit poorly).

Comment: Oh. But basically, now I'm trying to recreate the soda can as shown in the link under Cylinder Target. I've even got the image of that soda bottle to add to the target, but I am not sure of the dimensions to use. When I click Add an Image to target, it says error, not the same dimension, or something similar. I've used top/bottom radius 80 (mm) and height 100.

Comment: In the Target Manager. After creating your cylindrical target, it opens and visually shows the dimensions of the cylinder. Along with the option to upload side image (label) and when I do, it reads: 

"The image does not match the dimensions of the cylinder target. The ratio of the width to height of the image should be 2.513."

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: Ok, I read the whole thing myself. Figure it out. :S Thanks though! :D